# Blocking specific extensions in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a directory with files like:

```
/files/archive.01.json
/files/archive.02.json
/files/archive.03.json
/files/hello.php
```

I need the .htaccess to block access to all .json files in that directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Files "*.json">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: i meant in the .htaccess file

Comment: That _will_ work in .htaccess, unless the AllowOverride directive in httpd.conf has been set to prevent you doing so

Comment: And in Apache 2.4 syntax `Require all denied`