# NPM installing depencies for web application into public directory

Tags: npm

**NPM version 3.5.2**

**O/S: Ubuntu 18**

I am new to NPM and currently bogged down in a documentation swamp. I am developing a **web application** on a VM. This app will be stored in a code repository for others to pull, so I need to app to have everything it needs when deployed. This application has some Javascript dependencies (i.e. TinyMCE, DropZone, etc.) that need to be in the public directory instead of the project root.

Here is where most documentation on NPM fails me:

1. I want to install the packages **locally**.
2. I **don't** want to individually command install packages. I'd prefer my associates pull the repository with the package.json file in it and NPM install everything it needs accordingly.
3. I need the packages to go into a **public directory** so that my web app can use them.
4. My project will **not** itself be distributed as a package as much of the documentation assumes.

I need assistance configuring my package.json. This is the package.json I have to work with thus far.

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "tinymce": "^5.0.13",
    "dropzone": "^5.5.1"
  }
}
```

I'd prefer the package.json file define a custom path (into my ./public_html directory) as this file will be included in the project's repository. I've seen lots of references to defining the [installation path](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) here in the package.json file, but what if I want to define my version **and** a custom path. What is the syntax for this? Example?

Otherwise, I'm ok with it being in the install command, so long as it works, but I've not gotten this to work either.

```
npm install --prefix ./public_html
```

This command throws the error: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/projects/public_html/package.json'".

If a newer version of NPM would meet these needs more smoothly, I can attempt to update it.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

Move the package.json file into the public directory. For security concerns, you may block access to package.json and lock file [from .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1441616/676923).

**TL;DR**

I wanted my package.json file in the project root next to my composer.json file. This will make deploying updates clean and simple. After spending a few days researching this, I am concluding that this is beyond NPM's capabilities.

The simplest fix is to simply move the package.json file into the public directory and let NPM function there. This presents a small security problem in that you may not wish to expose your application dependencies (and their version numbers) to public view. You can block access to json files in .htaccess and that will sufficiently plug this hole.